# Vuetify helper classes and props

Tags: vuetify.js

Hi I come from bootstrap and Im trying to learn some vuetify. I had some questions about the framework that I couldnt find the answer to in the vuetify docs.

- What is a prop? (1)
- What is the difference between adding a prop and adding it as a class attr? (2)
- Is there a list where I can find all the props and helper classes for the components? (3)

For example: I was trying to make a container take the full width of the screen and couldnt find any property that the vuetify docs indicated that would make my container act like, this so I had to look online. I finally read on a stack overflow post that there was a prop called full-height that did exactly what I wanted. The problem was the conatiner docs said nothing about this prop in relation to the container itself. I also looked around the customization and the styles and animations tabs on the docs and could find anything about it. Where are all these props and helper classes defined?

Answer (score 1):

Vuetify uses Vue.js components, so you should be familiar with them.
However, I'll try to answer your 3 questions:

1. Props are a way to pass data to components. Say, for example, you are building a header component which needs to get the title from the page in which you put it in. Then, you can just declare a `title` property and then use that inside the component. You can then pass it like your standard HTML attributes, e.g. `<the-title title="Main Page" />` If the component is called `TheTitle`. For more thorough information, There is a [whole page](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) about props inside the official Vue.js docs.
2. In your use case, a class is useful when you have the appropriate CSS styling for it, otherwise it wouldn't do anything. My suggestion would be to use props for styling individual components where you don't have the same style anywhere else and classes for cases where a style repeats itself. If the style is local to the component, make sure you add `scoped` to the style tag to avoid applying it anywhere else.
3. Vuetify has a nice [API explorer](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/api-explorer/) which you can use to browse the entire collection of components. Each one has an API section where you can see all the details, including information about the props and other stuff.